# Comparing strings is giving false in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I am comparing two strings using `isEqual` method and it is giving `NO`.

```
if ([trie.name isEqual:string]) {
    isFound = YES;
    break;
}
```

The `trie.name` is a string initialized using `[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&uchar length:ucharLen]`, where `uchar` is a `unichar`. The `string` is a constant string `@"N"`. I have checked the hash values and both differ. I am not sure why creating a string using different initializer gives different hash for the same string value. In this case, how to check for string equality?

Please see the attached screenshot of the debug variables.

[image: string equal error]

---

Currently, I am using the code:

```
NSString *string = @"Pirates";
unichar uchar = [string characterAtIndex:0];
size_t ucharLen = sizeof(uchar);
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&uchar length:ucharLen];
XCTAssertTrue([str isEqual:@"P"]);
```

If I given the `length:` as 1, it works properly. How to get the length of the `unichar`. Will it always be `1` so that I can hardcode `1` in this case?

Comment: It seems your issue isn't with comparing strings. It's with using `[[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&uchar length:ucharLen]` and not getting the expected result. You should update your question showing all of the relevant code used to create the string.

Comment: @rmaddy Right, the problem was with the length in the initializer. I have updated the question.

Comment: Got it. The `initWithCharacters:` takes a C array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with:

```
unichar uchar = [string characterAtIndex:0];
size_t ucharLen = sizeof(uchar);
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&uchar length:ucharLen];
```

You are creating a string from a single `unichar` which means the length needs to be `1`. But the `sizeof(unichar)` returns 2 since `unichar` is a 16-bit (2-byte) value so you end up telling the string you are passing 2 characters, not 1.

So the resulting string contains two characters - the one you actually want and a second, random bit of garbage that happens to be at that memory address.

Just hardcode 1:

```
unichar uchar = [string characterAtIndex:0];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&uchar length:1];
```